# R (or stata):How to test a regression model where the null hypothesis is not that the coefficient is zero

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression, stata

For a class, I need to find the p-value for a simple linear regression (y=a*x+b, x and y are numeric) where the null hypothesis is that the coefficient is some value, lets say 100.
With the lm function in R, I know how to do a linear regression which gives me a coefficient and a p-value, where the p value is the probability that the coefficient is zero, the traditional null hypothesis.

can anyone help me with this ? is there a function that could allow me to test a particular model like that ?

Comment: The coefficient it reported with it's standard error. You can use that to calculate a p-value with that - subtract your fixed value from the coefficient and calculate a p-value normally.

Comment: I'd suggest migrating this question to stats.stackexchange as it's more about statistics than programming, but [there it would probably get marked as a duplicate of this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/337078/7515).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65044702/what-package-in-r-is-used-to-calculate-non-zero-null-hypothesis-p-values-on-line/65045375#65045375

Comment: In Stata you can use `test` to do that, for example `reg y x` followed by `test x = 100`.